# How to delete an ManyToMany related object when one part is empty?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, playframework

Here is the BlogPost model :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "blog_posts")
public class BlogPost extends Model {
    @Required
    @MaxSize(50)
    @MinSize(3)
    @Column(length=50)
    public String title;

    @Lob
    @Required
    @MaxSize(10000)
    public String description;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    public Date created;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity=PostTag.class, cascade=CascadeType.DETACH)
    @OrderBy("name ASC")
    public List<PostTag> tags;

        // + other fields
}
```

And the PostTag :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "post_tags")
public class PostTag extends Model {
    @Match("^([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{3,25})$")
    @MinSize(3)
    @MaxSize(25)
    @Required
    @Column(length=25, unique=true)
    public String name;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity=BlogPost.class, mappedBy="tags", cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)
    public List<BlogPost> posts;
}
```

The relation works fine, but what I'd like, is when I remove a tag from my post, if no other post use this tag, then I can remove it definitely from my database.

Here's the code I tried, but generate an Hibernate exception :

```
public boolean removeTag(PostTag tag) {
    if (!tags.contains(tag)) {
        return false;
    }

    tags.remove(tag);
    save();

    if (tag.posts == null || tag.posts.isEmpty()) {
        tag.delete();
    }

    return true;
}
```

The exact exception is:

```
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update   

java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

I tried to change CascadeType to DELETE_ORPHANS, but it's deprecated, and the new version only seems to works for OneToOne and OneToMany relationships only :/

How can I do ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If Im thinking about a tag correctly, wouldnt it be a OneToMany relationship with posts? One tag (object), many posts.

Comment: I thought about doing it like this, but with a ManyToMany, I can have a list of tags in Post, and unique tags in the Tags table.

Comment: With a OneToMany/ManyToOne you can still have a list of Tags in Post. Your logic for removing a tag would change. A better way to go about implementing this would be to have a single tag related to plenty of posts and keep the tag around regardless if posts are using it or not. Only delete the tag when it is requested to. This is how most blog systems work. Unless of course it is necessary for you to have a ManyToMany relationship.

Comment: If I use a OneToMany, I will have the foreign key in the Tags table pointing to Posts. I will still have many tags to one post, but if two posts use the same tag, I will have this tag twice in my Tags table, but with a different foreign key. (Or I am missing something!)

Comment: You can make sure that the tag is unique (I can recall how to do this in Django, but not with Play!/Hibernate). If anything, when adding tags to a post, just do a query to grab the tag being added. If the tag exists, assign it to the post. If an exception is thrown and it doesnt exist, create the tag and assign it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I've found where the problem was, so I'll explain it here in case someone have the same issue.

The exception was because I was trying to delete a Tag that still had relationship (it was not left alone).

Here is a working solution on how to delete Tags when there is no Posts using it anymore:

```
public boolean removeTag(PostTag tag) {
    if (!tags.contains(tag)) {
        return false;
    }

    tags.remove(tag);
    save();

    if (PostTag.find("name = ? AND size(posts) = 0", tag.name).first() != null) {
        tag.delete();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a bidirectional relation you should update the "backlink"

```
public boolean removeTag(PostTag tag) {
    if (!tags.contains(tag)) {
        return false;
    }

    tags.remove(tag);       //      remove post -> tag link

    tag.posts.remove(this); // added: remove tag -> post link

    save();

    if (tag.posts == null || tag.posts.isEmpty()) {
        tag.delete();
    }

    return true;
}
```