# Symfony delete ManyToMany related object when one part is empty?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, many-to-many

I'm trying to delete unused tags. Although the relationship between Post and Tag has been deleted, the post-linked tag is not deleted.

"orphanRemoval" does not work because it has deleted all. cascade "remove" does not delete.

Post Entity:

```
class Post implements \JsonSerializable
{
   /**
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Cms\PostTag", inversedBy="posts", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
    * @ORM\JoinTable(name="post_tag_taxonomy")
    * @Assert\Count(max="5")
    */
    private $tags;
}
```

Tag Entity:

```
class PostTag {
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Cms\Post", mappedBy="tags")
     */
     private $posts;
}
```

Here's a similar example, but for Java. [How to delete an ManyToMany related object when one part is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215094/how-to-delete-an-manytomany-related-object-when-one-part-is-empty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use `preUpdate` event from [Doctrine life cycle callbacks](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events). On the event of update a Post, you tell doctrine to check if there's a Tag change (in this case it's to NULL), if yes then query the Tag check if any posts still use it.

In short, you need to :

Add @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks before your class to enable life cycles.

Add preUpdate function in Post class :

```
    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     * @param PreUpdateEventArgs $event
     */
    public function clearChangeSet(PreUpdateEventArgs $event)
    {
        if ($event->hasChangedField('field_you_want_to_check') 
        ) {
            $em = $event->getEntityManager();
            // Now use the entityManager to query the tag and check.
        }
    }
```

By doing this doctrine will do the check for you, in the logic code you just need to perform the unlinking, no need to care about delete tags there.

Update : as pointed out, for associations in entity you cannot get the changes by `$event->hasChangedField`, use the method in [Symfony 3 / Doctrine - Get changes to associations in entity change set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45125857/symfony-3-doctrine-get-changes-to-associations-in-entity-change-set)

Comment: Yes, I tried, but you don't see the associated table changes here.

Comment: You can check this solution here to find the  associated table changes  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45125857/symfony-3-doctrine-get-changes-to-associations-in-entity-change-set

Comment: Thank you for the link. It was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
/**
 * @ORM\PostUpdate()
 */
public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    /** @var PersistentCollection $tags */
    $tags = $args->getEntity()->getTags();
    if ($tags->isDirty() && ($deleted = $tags->getDeleteDiff())) {
        $em = $args->getEntityManager();

        foreach ($deleted as $tag) {
            if ($tag->getPosts()->count() === 1) {
                $em->remove($tag);
                $em->flush($tag);
            }
        }
    }
}
```